# Tracking clicks within iframes with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, google-analytics

Any chance to track clicks and get referral traffic from iframe ?

I have tube video site, my videos is embeded on many others sites, but cant find solutions to track clicks on link inside iframe when video is embeded on other site

This is embeded code from my site

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/embed.php?id=4589"></iframe>
```

im try put inside embed.php something like this

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-111111-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('http:' == document.location.protocol ? 'http://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

And than im change link to this

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/video/55454.html" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);return false;">Continue</a>
```

But in this not a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add your default ga code inside a js file and include that in all your pages embed and video pages i.e embed.php, 55454.html etc

To trigger analytics on an event use the following,

```
//send to analytics
//    var _gaq = _gaq || []; //if already loaded e.g. single page app, keep comment out
//    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT']); //comment out if single page app
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/home/landingPage']);

//sendEventToAnalytics
//    var _gaq = _gaq || []; // if single
//    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT']); // if single
//    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); //if single
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, eventAtion, eventLabel]);
```

check out api in,
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: But im not sure that i can track clicks inside iframe in this way.. i'm already try this

Comment: If your link with the onclick handling is within the page that has your ga code, then you can track any event by calling the "sendEventToAnalytics" code i posted. All you need to do is call it from onclick or any other js event handling. When running as an iframe ga still work, for example in the past i realised that one of my apps where embeded as an iframe of a 3rd party page from ga.

Comment: So in embed.php for example i should use only `onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]);"` ? Cant understand where im make mistake...

Comment: Yes, but please check the way you include ga code. Try placing it inside head of embed.php, as it is instructed on https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080   check that it works, then use console to issue an event or just test you onclick part directly from the embed.php. If it works then test it as an iframe it should behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If the click is inside the iframe you should use:

```
window.parent._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', eventCategory, eventAtion, eventLabel]);
```